Laravel get table data from local server and store it back on online server
I am trying to get collection from my local database (order)table and store it to online database (order) table. Basically what I am doing now is

get all the order table data from local database and send it as order variable to blade
send back order variable to online database using ajax
store the order variable to online database (order) table

This last point (3) is where I am having an issue.
Here is how I get the data from the local database:
$orders = DB::table("orders")->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subHours(15))->latest()->get()->toArray();
     return $orders;

And this is the order variable I get on the blade:
[{"id":11,"drinkName":"Power Horse","drinkId":"19","drinkType":"Energy Drink","costPerDrink":"5000","totalOrdered":"8","totalOrderAmount":"40000","discount":null,"transactionId":null,"status":"Initiated","waitressName":"Jane","waitressId":"3","created_at":"2024-08-27 14:52:56","updated_at":"2024-08-27 14:52:56"},id":10,"drinkName":"Coke","drinkId":"9","drinkType":"Chasers","costPerDrink":"1000","totalOrdered":"3","totalOrderAmount":"3000","discount":null,"transactionId":null,"status":"Initiated","waitressName":"Jane","waitressId":"3","created_at":"2024-08-27 14:52:49","updated_at":"2024-08-27 14:52:49"},{"id":9,"drinkName":"Crystal","drinkId":"1","drinkType":"Champagne","costPerDrink":"800000","totalOrdered":"3","totalOrderAmount":"2400000","discount":null,"transactionId":null,"status":"Initiated","waitressName":"Jane","waitressId":"3","created_at":"2024-08-27 14:52:41","updated_at":"2024-08-27 14:52:41"}]

This is how I send it to the online server:
function oneSecondFunction(){ 
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST', 
    url:"mysite/app/api/testItem",
    data:{orders : orders, _token: "<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>" },
    success:function(data){                     
      console.log(data);                     
    }
    }); 
}

What I get at the online server:
[{&quot;id&quot;:11,&quot;drinkName&quot;:&quot;Power Horse&quot;,&quot;drinkId&quot;:&quot;19&quot;,&quot;drinkType&quot;:&quot;Energy Drink&quot;,&quot;costPerDrink&quot;:&quot;5000&quot;,&quot;totalOrdered&quot;:&quot;8&quot;,&quot;totalOrderAmount&quot;:&quot;40000&quot;,&quot;discount&quot;:null,&quot;transactionId&quot;:null,&quot;status&quot;:&quot;Initiated&quot;,&quot;waitressName&quot;:&quot;Jane&quot;,&quot;waitressId&quot;:&quot;3&quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2024-08-27 14:52:56&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2024-08-27 14:52:56&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:10,&quot;drinkName&quot;:&quot;Coke&quot;,&quot;drinkId&quot;:&quot;9&quot;,&quot;drinkType&quot;:&quot;Chasers&quot;,&quot;costPerDrink&quot;:&quot;1000&quot;,&quot;totalOrdered&quot;:&quot;3&quot;,&quot;totalOrderAmount&quot;:&quot;3000&quot;,&quot;discount&quot;:null,&quot;transactionId&quot;:null,&quot;status&quot;:&quot;Initiated&quot;,&quot;waitressName&quot;:&quot;Jane&quot;,&quot;waitressId&quot;:&quot;3&quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2024-08-27 14:52:49&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2024-08-27 14:52:49&quot;},{&quot;id&quot;:9,&quot;drinkName&quot;:&quot;Crystal&quot;,&quot;drinkId&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;drinkType&quot;:&quot;Champagne&quot;,&quot;costPerDrink&quot;:&quot;800000&quot;,&quot;totalOrdered&quot;:&quot;3&quot;,&quot;totalOrderAmount&quot;:&quot;2400000&quot;,&quot;discount&quot;:null,&quot;transactionId&quot;:null,&quot;status&quot;:&quot;Initiated&quot;,&quot;waitressName&quot;:&quot;Jane&quot;,&quot;waitressId&quot;:&quot;3&quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2024-08-27 14:52:41&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2024-08-27 14:52:41&quot;}] 

How can I store this at the online order table? any code samples and guidance are welcomed.


how is your mysite/app/api/testItem handling the data? 2. How is order presented in your javascript before ajax?


I was able to solve it by using the below code to send the order variable to server
function oneSecondFunction(){ 
             
                   
                    var data = {!! json_encode($orders) !!};

                    $.ajax({ 
                        url:"mysite/app/api/testItem",
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                            data: data
                        },
                        success: function(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            console('An error occurred');
                        }
                    });

}

The above gave me the exact (order)response I needed at the online server to insert the order variable at the online database (order) table.
